# Why are the elements of GF(q), whose characteristic is 2, all squares?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

If $a\in GF(2^n)$, then there is the element in $GF(2^n)$ such that $x^2 = a$.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

For a finite field $F$, the multipülicative group $F^\times$ is cyclic of order $|F|-1$.